# How can I show User Message after insertion using php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have written my php query using PDO inside a try and catch, and I want to show user alert message whether form has been submitted or not.
Here is the code I have written, Although record is successfully inserted but my closable div message is not showing in browser.

```
<?php 
include('conn.php');
if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
try {

$userName       = $_POST['user_name'];
$userPassword   =$_POST['user_password'];
$userRole       = $_POST['user_role'];
$Name           = $_POST['name'];
$userEmail      = $_POST['email'];
$user = $_SESSION['adminid'];
$status         = 0;
$created        = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password, user_role, name, email, status, creation_date, created_by) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$userName, $userPassword, $userRole, $Name, $userEmail, $status, $created, $user ]);
$result = $stmt->rowCount();
if($result){

echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  User Added Successfully!  
</div>';
}else{

echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  User could NOT be Added!  
</div>';
    }
    

} catch (Exception $e) {

echo $e->getMessage();

}
}
?>
```

Comment: just echo it right after execution, no need for that rowCount()

Comment: neither try catch is needed